Sound device disconnected
I use Lenovo T430 Thinkpad (Type 2349) laptop.
Allegedly, I have a Realtek HD Audio device.
My sound device is disconnected.
I am not being able to fix this issue.
So far I have tried:

Removing the existing driver and rebooting. The audio driver was supposed to be installed automatically. It didn't.
Installing Realtek HD Audio driver v6.0.1.7240. Nothing changed.
Updating drivers using the free version of PC HelpSoft Driver Updater. The app failed because of the disconnected device.
Running sound device troubleshooter "Find & Fix problems with playing sound." The troubleshooter couldn't detect any problem.

What should I do now to fix this issue?






Have you tried booting thru some Live Linux Distro like Linux Mint Live? Does it detect the audio thru Live Linux? Any Restore Points created in Windows to try to fall back on?

@patkim, No. No. No.

You might try doing as @patkim suggests, i.e., test if the hardware is bad by booting a Live Linux USB (or Hiren's BootCD Pe). That said, if the Realtek audio works, then try using DISM and SFC to fix the issue in Windows, or reinstall Windows 10 from ISO.

DISM and SFC commands are available on the net. However for quick ref here they are. Try them in admin command prompt. dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth  and then sfc /scannow

What I realized was that I accidentally deleted some unidentified Windows system files before removing the Realtek audio driver. As a result, the sound devices became unplugged.
So, what I did was:

using PC HelpSoft Driver Updater, first I updated the chipset drivers.

Then I rebooted the PC.

Then I installed the Realtek 2013 HD Audio driver downloaded from DriverScape.com.

After a second reboot, my audio is back again.


